# Stray characters in output when using Docker's Go SDK

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to convert the `io.ReadCloser` (interface) that I am getting after running the Docker image via Go `docker-sdk` to `[]byte` for further use.

When I read from the `io.ReadCloser` using `stdcopy.StdCopy` to `stdout`, it prints the data perfectly.

The code `stdcopy.StdCopy(os.Stderr, os.Stdout, out)` prints:

```html
Content-Type: text/html




<html>
<head><title>HTML response</title></head>
<body><h1>Hello, Goodbye</h1></body>
</html>
```

Because I need to send this entire content as a Response I need to convert the content to `[]byte` or `string`. But, once I convert the `io.ReadCloser` to `[]byte` or `string` using any method but `stdcopy.StdCopy`, it adds a special character to some lines.

The snippet I used to read from `out` to `buf` using `*bytes.Buffer.ReadFrom`:

```golang
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(out)
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

Prints:

```html
Content-Type: text/html




<html>
*<head><title>HTML response</title></head>
%<body><h1>Hello, Goodbye</h1></body>
</html>
```

As you can see extra characters like `*` and `%` are being added. I have also tried `ioutil.ReadAll` function as well, no luck. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you describe your `out`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are stray bytes like `*`, `%`, etc. prefixed with some of the lines.

The stray bytes appear to be a custom stream multiplexing protocol, allowing `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to be sent down the same connection.

Using `stdcopy.StdCopy()` interprets these custom headers and those stray characters are avoided by removing the protocol header for each piece of data.

Refer: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/stdcopy/stdcopy.go#L42

```
// Write sends the buffer to the underneath writer.
// It inserts the prefix header before the buffer,
// so stdcopy.StdCopy knows where to multiplex the output.
// It makes stdWriter to implement io.Writer.
```

So, `stdcopy.StdCopy` is your friend and an alternative for `io.Copy` and friends when working with Docker.

A sample example to give you an idea:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

var resp string = `
Content-Type: text/html
<html>
<head><title>HTML response</title></head>
<body><h1>Hello, Goodbye</h1></body>
</html>`

func main() {
    src := strings.NewReader(resp)
    dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
    _, _ = io.Copy(dst, src)
    fmt.Println(dst.String())
    // Output:
    //
    // Content-Type: text/html
    // <html>
    // <head><title>HTML response</title></head>
    // <body><h1>Hello, Goodbye</h1></body>
    // </html>
}
```

Signature for: `func io.Copy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader)`
As `dst` `(*bytes.Buffer)` has a `Write` method and hence it implements the `io.Writer` interface and it works.

Now use the same idea when using `stdcopy.StdCopy()` as the signature is the same. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stdcopy#StdCopy